# A question about particular solution of Heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I have a question on particular solution of 1-D Heat equation
$$\frac{\partial^{2} T(x, t)}{\partial x^{2}}=\frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{\partial T(x, t)}{\partial t} \quad \text { in } \quad 0<x<\infty, \quad t>0$$
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text { BC1: } & T(x=0)=f(t) \\
\text { BC2: } & T(x \rightarrow \infty)=0 \\
\text { IC: } & T(x, t=0)=0
\end{array}$$

It is well known that the analytical solution of this equation is given by

$$T(x, t)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{4 \pi \alpha}} \int_{\tau=0}^{t} \frac{f(\tau)}{(t-\tau)^{3 / 2}} \exp \left[\frac{-x^{2}}{4 \alpha(t-\tau)}\right] d \tau$$
Now if $f(\tau)=Asin(\omega\tau)$, then the solution that satisfies this equation could be also written as (particular solution)
$$T(x, t)=Ae^{-x / d}[\sin (\omega t-x / d)]$$ where
$$d=(2 \alpha /\omega)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$since this solution also satisfies the original Heat equation. However when I compare them I noticed that they are not same (I plot them in Matlab and found that the temperature profile are not same). Since this problem is well-posed so I assume the solution is unique, but the particular solution is widely used in research, is it a wrong solution?

What's the relationship between the analytical solution and particular solution? Also the limit of analytical solution as $t\rightarrow 0$ is not $f(\tau)$ since the Heat equation is defined as $0<x<\infty$, is there a discontinuity at $t=0$?

Thank for the help.

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti Yes and that's also a problem. Will particular solution converges to analytical solution as $t\rightarrow \infty$? Since as $t$ becomes large, the impact of initial condition should be neglected, is that right? I believe people chose this particular in research field for a reason.

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti How did you verify the particular solution is the asymptotic form? Could you please tell me the method? Thanks!